# How do I compare a JSON object with a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, equals

I am developing this website layout for http://myttc.ca. I was successful at retrieving most of the data and displaying it on the page.

But when I had to filter my search to find only the stop names that had only Subways, I get stuck with errors. Here is the JSON page, http://myttc.ca/finch_station.json. Here, when I try to access only the stops having the route name as `Yonge-University-Spadina Subway`, I get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'equals' of undefined`. I also tried simply putting `===` operator. Maybe I have to unserialize or something, but totally helpless now after going throughout the internet to fix this problem. I am a newbie to javaScript and I think maybe I'm missing something here. Here is my code so far:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        // retrieving the data.
        $.getJSON("http://myttc.ca/finch_station.json?callback=?", function(data){
          //Storing the string in variable.   
          var subway="Yonge-University-Spadina Subway";

          console.log(data);
          //Displaying the station name first in a div called "stations" in the body.
          $("#stations").append('Station: ' + data.name + '<br/>');

          //Iterating through the stops array to display each stop name 
          $.each(data.stops, function(i,stopz){

          $("#stations").append('&nbsp;&nbsp;Stop: ' + stopz.name + '<br/>');
          //This is my problem area.Not able to compare the routes.name to the string.   
          if(stopz.routes.name === subway) {
            $.each(stopz.routes, function(i,routez) {
              //Displaying the Departure time and shape of the stops.
              $.each(routez.stop_times, function(i,timez) {
                $("#stations").append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Departure-time: ' + timez.departure_time + ' || Shape: ' + timez.shape + '<br/>');  
              });
            });
            }
          });
         });
       });
     </script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="stations">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use your browser's debugger - Chrome's developer tools, IE's developer tools, Firefox's Firebug addon (all started up with F12). Undefined means you're using an undeclared variable. Find out what it is that way.

Comment: ..by a quick look i find that the "name" property belongs to "routes" array; try to $.each that.

Answer (score 1):

Given the format of your stops data format:

```
{"routes":[],"name":"Finch Station GO Hallway","uri":"finch_station_go_hallway","agency":"Toronto Transit Commission"}
```

Your reference to `stopz.routes.name` is invalid.  I think what you meant was `stopz.name`.  So your code should look like:

```
            if(stopz.name === subway)
            {
                $.each(stopz.routes, function(i,routez){
                    // ... etc ...
                });
            }
```